# Delete specific fcurve in python

Tags: python, animation, scripting, fcurves

Hello all blenderheads ! 
i'm trying to write a simple tool to split a frame in piece with the great animated render border addon ! so far so good, all's working but i need a way to delete the created keyframes of the border render, i can't figure it out !
so far i've got :

```
for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
for fcurves in scene.animation_data.action.fcurves:
    if fcurves.data_path.startswith("animated_render_border"):
        fcurves.animation_data_clear()
```

The startswith method work to change interpolation of the keyframe, so my problem comes from the

```
fcurves.animation_data_clear()
```

I tried several other ways, nothing works... any idea out there ?
Thanks you all !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you know the scenes animation fcurves are found in

```
fc = bpy.context.scene.animation_data.action.fcurves
```

The fcurves list has a remove method -

```
fc.remove(fc[0])
```

Which leads to changing your code to

```
for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
    fcurves = scene.animation_data.action.fcurves
    for c in fcurves:
        if c.data_path.startswith("animated_render_border"):
            fcurves.remove(c)
```

Comment: perfect thank you very much sir ! i tried this one, but did'nt fill the () argument, didn't really get it ! (sorry, new to python) Works like a charm !