# How to remove all only rotation keyframes from current action with Python?

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine

How to remove only rotation keyframes from current action with Python? Or location keyframes? Or scale? Is it passible?

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75002/delete-specific-fcurve-in-python)

Answer (score 4):

**Using [`FCurve.remove`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.ActionFCurves.html?highlight=fcurve%20remove#bpy.types.ActionFCurves.remove)**

The curve, as shown in graph editor,  with keyframe points for each keyframe value pair is an fcurve.  Removing an fcurve Will remove all keyframes for that [`FCurve.data_path`](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75002/delete-specific-fcurve-in-python), [`Fcurve.array_index`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.FCurve.html?highlight=fcurve%20index#bpy.types.FCurve.array_index) pair

Similarly to this [related (possible duplicate)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75002/delete-specific-fcurve-in-python) question.  Example script removes all Location, Rotation and Scale fcurves from an action.  It tests the [`FCurve.data_path`](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75002/delete-specific-fcurve-in-python) against the keyframe type list `["location", "rotation", "scale"]`.  Note `"rotation"` will match `"rotation_euler"` or `"rotation_quaternion"` etc, which will be the actual datapath (as there is no `Object.rotation`).

Avoided using the [`FCurves.find`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.ActionFCurves.html?highlight=fcurve%20remove#bpy.types.ActionFCurves.find) method with a list comprehension, and used `pop` to avoid possibly referencing a removed fcurve later.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context
ob = context.object
ad = ob.animation_data

if ad:
    action = ad.action
    if action:
        remove_types = ["location", "scale", "rotation"]
        # select all that have datapath above
        fcurves = [fc for fc in action.fcurves
                for type in remove_types
                if fc.data_path.startswith(type)
                ]
        # remove fcurves
        while(fcurves):
            fc = fcurves.pop()
            action.fcurves.remove(fc)
```

To remove only y axis Loc, Rot and Scale also test for the [`Fcurve.array_index`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.FCurve.html?highlight=fcurve%20index#bpy.types.FCurve.array_index) property which is 0, 1, 2 for x, y, z respectively.

```
        fcurves = [fc for fc in action.fcurves
                for type in remove_types
                if fc.data_path.startswith(type)
                and fc.array_index == 1
                ]
```